# column order in datastage Source db Connectors

Tags: sql, database, etl, datastage

I am updating a series of datastage jobs, where some of the updates include modifying database source connectors.

In the columns tab, I see the list of columns and their datatypes, however, I need to inject columns into that table in a certain order. The SQL statement is a compounded statement, and not just a table read, so the columns are not just from one table.

In the columns tab, I do not see any way to re-order the columns.  Am I missing a shortcut or something that allows me to re-order the columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Connector stages it is possible to reorder columns by selecting one and dragging it with the right mouse button pressed to another position. This is tested in the DB2 Connector stage.

Additional option:
As the column (table definition) is bound to the link you could also change the column order in the output tab of the previous stage.

Comment: It didn't work in the Netezza Connector Stage, but it did work in the JOIN stage afterwards while in the INPUT Column tab.  You sir are a genius.  Thank you so much.